# Activate Device Admininstrator after Application installed

Tags: android, uninstallation, administrator

I want to disable application uninstallation after the application installed, I have try code from here : http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1351/

```
 <receiver android:name="android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:label="@string/admin_app"
            android:description="@string/admin_app_description"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"  android:resource="@xml/admin_app_config"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But, using that code, I still must Activate Device Administrator by myself to disable application uninstallation, is there a setting to make device administrator activate after install the app ?

Comment: only user can grant admin access to application you must navigate to admin access page to grant access or your app must be system app.

Comment: so there is no way to make that activate setting on automatically with code ? @piyush

Comment: No.  The whole point is the app is doing serious stuff to the device that the user must first consent to.

Comment: is there a way to reverse it, like if Device Manager not Activate, app can't be uninstalled and vice versa ? @piyush

Comment: no same installation process is also user based if you application is device admin the user doesn't get directly uninstall it user have to de activate the admin first but you can get the call back when user de activate your app from admin right you can lock the device and prohibit user from doing so but for all this to happen user must make you application admin first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words **No** you should have user consent first.

The only way to do this silently is on rooted device where your app can be made system application and you can write secure setting database through you application to make your app device admin.